# How come the Doctor and Clara will never be able to see each other again?

Tags: doctor-who

The Doctor and Clara always had fun times together but their time came to a end in *Face The Raven*. After their last goodbyes, the Doctor goes 4.5 billion years in the confession dial to save Clara and tells her what has happend to her:

> DOCTOR: Your heartbeat. Your physical processes have been time looped. Frozen between one heartbeat and the next. Even your breathing is just a habit. You don't need it.

They they argue about whose memory will be erased:

> DOCTOR: It won't hurt, it'll be nothing. You'll just pass out for a moment.
>
> CLARA: And then?
>
> DOCTOR: When you wake, you'll be fine.
>
> CLARA: But
>
> DOCTOR: Clara, just listen to me.
>
> CLARA: Just say it. Say it. Come on. Tell me.
>
> DOCTOR: When you wake up, you will have forgotten me. You'll have forgotten we ever even met.
>
> CLARA: And why would I want that?
>
> DOCTOR: Because it's the only way. That stuff in your head, the image of me, they could use it to find you.

This becomes important for both of them:

> DOCTOR: I'm trying to keep you safe.
>
> CLARA: Why? Nobody's ever safe. I've never asked you for that, ever. These have been the best years of my life, and they are mine. Tomorrow is promised to no one, Doctor, but I insist upon my past. I am entitled to that. It's mine.
>
> DOCTOR: You and me together. Look how far I went, for fear of losing you. This has to stop. One of us has to go

Then the Doctor uses it and his memory of Clara is erased. Then he is outside, and goes to a diner to talk to a waitress about Clara. Then they both go off on new adventures in their TARDISes never to see each other again, which made me think: how come the Doctor and Clara will never be able to see each other again?

Comment: Is this not explained by the quotes in your question?

Comment: Spoiler alert: They saw each other again. Unless the Doctor was imagining it before his regeneration.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Because it's not safe for them to be together any more.

In their discussion at the end of the universe, the Doctor and Ashildr talk about what he's planning to do to Clara and why:

> ASHILDR: What if the Hybrid wasn't one person, but two?
>   DOCTOR: Two?
>   ASHILDR: A dangerous combination of a passionate and powerful Time Lord and a young woman so very similar to him. Companions who are willing to push each other to extremes.
>   DOCTOR: She's my friend. She's just my friend.
>   ASHILDR: How did you meet her?
>   DOCTOR: Missy.
>   ASHILDR: Missy. The Master. The lover of chaos, who wants you to love it, too. She's quite the matchmaker.
>   DOCTOR: Clara's my friend.
>   ASHILDR: I know. And you're willing to risk all of Time and Space because you miss her. One wonders what the pair of you will get up to next.
>   DOCTOR: Nothing. Nothing at all. **I know I went too far. I get it. That's why I'm doing what I'm doing.**
>   ASHILDR: And what would that be?
>   DOCTOR: I'm taking her back to Earth. Somewhere safe, somewhere out of the way. **I'm going to wipe her memory of every last detail of me. It'll be like our friendship never happened.**
>   [...]
>   CLARA: So what happens now? Hey? Me and you, what do we do now?
>   DOCTOR: I'm not sure you managed to reverse the polarity. I'm not even sure that you can. It'll do something to one of us. Better than flipping a coin.
>   CLARA: Doctor?
>   DOCTOR: You and me together. **Look how far I went, for fear of losing you. This has to stop. One of us has to go.**
>
> <sub>-- Series 9 Episode 12, *Hell Bent* (emphasis mine)</sub>

Summing up that long transcript quote:

- the Doctor and Clara together form the Hybrid (an incredibly dangerous creature of prophecy)
- already they've nearly destroyed the universe in order to be together
- they can't keep on travelling together for fear of what they might do next.

---

By the way, ignore this bit:

> DOCTOR: When you wake up, you will have forgotten me. You'll have forgotten we ever even met.
>   CLARA: And why would I want that?
>   DOCTOR: Because it's the only way. That stuff in your head, the image of me, they could use it to find you.

The Doctor tells Clara he's going to wipe her memory so that "they" (the Time Lords?) wouldn't be able to find her, but this contradicts the above. It's just a lie he makes up before realising she knows his real motivation because she's been watching him and Ashildr on the scanner.

Comment: how the hell did the doctor and clara  already  nearly destroyed the universe in order to be together

Comment: @AndrewCasali The Doctor spent 4.5 billion years punching a wall so that he could save her from dying in Trap Street, an act which (according to the Gallifreyan general) **could fracture Time itself**.

Comment: how are the doctor and clara the hybrid the hybrid is a creature destined to conquere gallifrey and stand in its ruins

Comment: @AndrewCasali That's what it said in the episode. Note that the Doctor *did* conquer Gallifrey in that episode, and they would have stood in its ruins if they'd stayed together.

Comment: this dosent make any sense they can't keep on travelling together for their own sakes and the sake of the universe. what own sakes?

Comment: @AndrewCasali Hmm, maybe it's not so much for their own sakes as for the sake of the universe. Edited that bit out.

Comment: Any time I read "that doesn't make any sense" in a Doctor Who question, I laugh inside...

Comment: i know the doctor is a passionate and powerful Time Lord but clara is a young woman so very similar to him. clara very similer to the doctor ? i dont see it

Comment: @AndrewCasali We already talked about that in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38080/discussion-between-rand-althor-and-andrew-casali), remember? They were really pushing this theme in the last two series of Clara becoming just like the Doctor; I don't know how you could have missed it.

Comment: oh sorry forgot i thought her being the doctor was really stupid we all know there one true doctor and thats the timelord the Doctor  she cant master what the doctor does in all of his 13 incarnations William Hartnell, Patrick Troughton, Jon Pertwee, Tom Baker, Peter Davison, Colin Baker, Sylvester McCoy, Paul McGann, John Hurt, Christopher Eccleston, David Tennant, Matt Smith, Peter Capaldi

Comment: @tilley31 when you aid i laugh at dont make sense i say that not cool man your mean